# OutOfMemory exception while using ScaleTransform in Windows 8.1 Store App

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, .net-4.5

I've completely failed to understand the reason why i get this exception so it would be nice if someone would be so kind to look at my project and suggest any reasons for the issue. I understand it's quite difficult to look at unknown project so even any tips would also be nice.

Problem description: i've ported my own ZoomControl from WPF to StoreApp and use it to zoom in/out graph using **ScaleTransform**. When i work on default/far zooming level all seems fine and no memory spikes occur but as i zoom-in deeper **unmanaged** memory usage burst very high and fast resulting in OOM exception. I've profiled using dotMemory and tried to isolate different parts related to zooming including animation cut off and template simplifying to no avail.

Another strange thing i've noted: if you zoom in w/o crash and alt+tab to task Manager you'll see significant memory usage drop, then if you'll back to app and pan content with the mouse (don't touching zoom) you'll got lag and can see huge memory usage spike in Task Manager.

The weird thing is that it works fine on one zoom level and crash on the other, This is mind blowing. I just don't understand why there is so high memory usage in zoomed in state.

I'm working on open-source project you can [get here](https://github.com/panthernet/GraphX). Run **METRO.SimpleGraph** project and use mousewheel to zoom in.